# Redirect people after SSL is set up

Tags: server, apache2, ssl

how do I set up the auto redirect with apache2. I have got SSL working and want to redirect all to the SSL side. I added Redirect / https://fraffel.tech/ but takes me to the wrong site directory whereas https takes me to the right spot. Is that the right thing to add for the redirect? (its in VirtualHost *:80)

Current VirtualHost file:

```
ServerName fraffel.tech 

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/fraffeltech
    Redirect / https://fraffel.tech/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443> 
    DocumentRoot /var/www/fraffeltech

    SSLEngine on 
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/fraffel_tech.crt 
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/fraffel.tech.key 
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/fraffel_tech.ca-bundle 
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the directive `ServerName` is missing within the `<VirtualHost>` tags. This is necessary to identify the virtual host.

Also, for this case, it is a good idea to use the directive `Redirect` with the option `permanent` - read the section "Redirect Methods" in [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-apache-and-nginx).

```bsh
ServerName example.com # This directive provides a global server name.
                       # But you should set ServerName also for each virtual host
                       # to identify it!!!

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    # Redirect Requests to HTTPS with HTTP 301 status
    Redirect permanent "/" "https://example.com/"

    # Other configuration directives...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerName example.com

    # Other configuration directives...
</VirtualHost>
```

Apply the configuration change and restart (or reload) Apache. Then flush your browser's cache or use an incognito window (or another browser) to see the change.

---

For this task you can use also rewrite rules as it is illustrated in [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/424743/364207), but within the Apaches documentation you will [be advised](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/avoid.html#redirect) to do not use the rewrite engine when you can use more simple directives.

Comment: Thanks heaps. Works in Firefox, just got to fix it in edge probably a cache issue.

Comment: @FRAFFELMEDIA, yes, I can confirm I was redirected to `https` when opened your site.