# Breaking links with apache2 after SSL installation

Tags: server, apache2, ssl

I have installed my SSL and set up redirects but now some links are breaking

Example I'm getting `https://fraffel.techadmin/` instead of `https://fraffel.tech/admin`. It's like the system is moving the forwardslash to the end, in the website files it is defined as `https://fraffel.tech/admin`

Any help extremely appreciated.

Comment: Hello, FRAFFEL MEDIA, probably you should put a slash `/` to the end of the target URL within the redirection directive: `Redirect permanent "/" "https://example.com/"`. I've checked for [examples](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/avoid.html#redirect) within the Apache's documentation and also corrected [my previous answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1031460/566421).

Comment: You are welcome! Please do not worry to ask clarifying questions under an accepted answer or even to un-accept an answer if you later find it is not working properly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [examples](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/avoid.html#redirect), provided within the Apache's documentation, you should add a slash to the end of the target URL in the `Redirect` directive.

```bsh
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName example.com

    # Redirect Requests to HTTPS
    Redirect permanent "/" "https://example.com/"

    # Other configuration directives for this VH ...

</VirtualHost>
```

Don't forget to restart Apache and flush the browser's cache to take effect.

---

I know that, because I led you to this situation with my [my previous answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1031460/566421), that is already corrected :)