# How should I configure multiple virtual hosts with a single configuration file in Apache?

Tags: apache2, ssl

**System**

```
Linux hosek 4.15.0-48-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 3 08:28:49 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Issue**

How should I configure multiple virtual hosts with a single configuration file in Apache using ssl with redirecting?

What is needed and not needed in my configuration below? Is possible for example set `Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/hosek/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/hosek/privkey.pem` to begin of file only? For all `vhost`s?

Is possible to make whole configuration to one file, especially one `VirtualHost`? I have 2 files now, one for `80`, second for `443`.

Example of my `vhost`s.

`no-ssl.conf`file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.thehatmakers.cz
ServerAlias thehatmakers.cz
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(thehatmakers.cz) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.thehatmakers.cz$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.thehatmakers.cz
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.obrazduse.cz
ServerAlias obrazduse.cz
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(obrazduse.cz) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.obrazduse.cz$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.obrazduse.cz
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

`ssl.conf` file.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.thehatmakers.cz
ServerAlias thehatmakers.cz
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(thehatmakers.cz) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.thehatmakers.cz$1 [R=301,L]
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/thehatmakers
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/hosek/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/hosek/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.obrazduse.cz
ServerAlias obrazduse.cz
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(obrazduse.cz) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.obrazduse.cz$1 [R=301,L]
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/obrazduse
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/hosek/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/hosek/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks.

**Update**

If not possible to do with 1 VirtualHost, what about this configuration? Is any shorter way to do this? Is possible to use `Redirect` for ssl? As I have commented for `*:443` configuration? Can I use `Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/hosek/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/hosek/privkey.pem`
 outside `VirtualHost` configuration? And what about google, is it ok with this redirecting? I am using 1 certificate for all domains, is it ok?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.thehatmakers.cz
ServerAlias thehatmakers.cz
Redirect / https://www.thehatmakers.cz
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.thehatmakers.cz
ServerAlias thehatmakers.cz
#Redirect / https://www.thehatmakers.cz
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(thehatmakers.cz) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.thehatmakers.cz$1 [R=301,L]
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/thehatmakers
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/hosek/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/hosek/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When does Ubuntu 16.04 use /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/900400/when-does-ubuntu-16-04-use-etc-apache2-ssl-apache-crt) Also: [Redirect people after SSL is set up](https://askubuntu.com/q/1031457/566421)

Comment: @pa4080 Hi, this is not duplicate, because there are no `ServerAlias` options, and there is not answered if I can use both `80` and `443` in 1 `VirtualHost` configuration.

Comment: Hi, @genderbee. If you have an alias used within HTTPS/SSL virtual host you need to issue certificates for the both domain names: `sudo letsencrypt --apache .... -d www.example.com -d example.com` - they will be placed in the same certificate file. You can place the definitions for the VH on port 80 and for the VH on port 443 in one file, but there is no way to configure one virtual host to listen on two ports.

Comment: @pa4080 Thanks. And what about `Redirect` instead `Rewrite` in ssl config? See my update please. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, @genderbee, I've created more structured answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the proposed [duplication](https://askubuntu.com/q/900400/566421) here are few answers specific to this question:

> How do I setup HTTPS virtual host with `ServerAlias` in use.

If you are using `ServerAlias` directive within HTTPS/SSL virtual host you need to issue certificates for all domain names. By using `letsencrypt` you will need to add few `-d` options:

```
sudo letsencrypt --apache .... -d www.example.com -d example.com
```

All certificates will be placed in the same certificate file.

> Is it possible to make whole configuration to one file, especially one VirtualHost? I have 2 files now, one for 80, second for 443.

You can place the definitions for all VirtualHosts in one file, thus it will be easy to enable and disable all of them together. But there is no way to configure one VirtualHost to listen on two ports.

> What about `Redirect` instead `Rewrite` in ssl config?

According to Apache2's documentation for such cases it is better to use the `Redirect` directive instead of `Rewrite` rules. Note, you need to create two separate VirtualHosts if you want to redirect `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`. All related VirtualHosts can use the same certificate file, generated in the way described above.

Each virtual host will be responsible for a different `ServerName`, for example: `ServerName example.com` for the first, respectively  `ServerName www.example.com` for the second, etc. Note the `ServerAlias` directive must be removed.

If everything works as expected, you can keep using `Rewrite` rules - this is subject of your decision. If you are using `Redirect` directive, [do not miss the slash at the end](https://askubuntu.com/a/1031556/566421) of the target domain name! Here is an example for HTTPS VirtualHost that uses the `Redirect` directive.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName thehatmakers.cz
    Redirect permanent "/" "https://www.thehatmakers.cz/"

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/hosek/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/hosek/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

- You do not need anything else for this VirtualHost.
- The keyword `permanent` will instruct the client's browser to do this redirection automatically next time.
- `Redirect` = HTTP 302
- `Redirect permanent` = HTTP 301

Comment: Hi, thanks. Then shortest and best configuration of this is as I wrote in update of my question, because there is only one redirect for all domains.

Comment: @genderbee, yes your updated example looks good. You just need one additional slash `/` at the end of `Redirect / https://www.thehatmakers.cz` >> `Redirect / https://www.thehatmakers.cz/`.

Comment: It works without `/` at the end too. ;)

Comment: @genderbee, yes it works when you are using `http://example.com`, but when there is any URI, like `http://example.com/something` it is highly possible to get redirection to `https://example.comsomething` ... when you are doing such tests use a new *incognito window* or different browser, or be sure your browser's cache is flushed.

Comment: Thanks for info.