# apache2 is directing to wrong path

Tags: server, apache2

i follow this link to set vhosts https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04
and managed to get `first site` at `var/www/html` and `second site` `var/www/secondsite.com/public_html` working good till now

i followd same process as before from that page .

example.com with document path  `/home/user/folder/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder`

now the problem is `firstsite.com` gives `firstsite.com` and `secondsite.com` gives `secondsite.com` but `example.com` is not giving `document path` it is giving `secondsite.com`

what could be problem??

here is the conf 's 
apache2.conf

```
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
# the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
# hints.
#
#
# Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
# The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
# upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
# default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
# virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
# order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
# possible.

# It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
# below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
#
#   /etc/apache2/
#   |-- apache2.conf
#   |   `--  ports.conf
#   |-- mods-enabled
#   |   |-- *.load
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   |-- conf-enabled
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   `-- sites-enabled
#       `-- *.conf
#
#
# * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
#   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
#   web server.
#
# * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
#   customized anytime.
#
# * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
#   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
#   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
#   respectively.
#
#   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
#   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
#   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
#   their respective man pages for detailed information.
#
# * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
#   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
#   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
#   work with the default configuration.


# Global configuration
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
# Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
# "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf


# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>



<Directory /home/ogp_agent/OGP_User_Files/19/screenshots/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>


# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive.
#
# These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
# (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
# requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
# requests.
#
# Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
# Use mod_remoteip instead.
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
ServerName 139.xx.xx.xx`

000-default.conf
`<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com


    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.con
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =subdomain.firstsite.tk
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet

<VirtualHost *:80>


<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
        AddHandler php56-fcgi-www .php
        Action php56-fcgi-www /php56-fcgi-www
        Alias /php56-fcgi-www /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php56-fcgi-www
        FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php56-fcgi-www -socket /run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
              Require all granted
         </Directory>
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
        AddHandler php71-fcgi-www .php
        Action php71-fcgi-www /php71-fcgi-www
         Alias /php71-fcgi-www /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php71-fcgi-www
         FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php71-fcgi-www -socket /run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock -idle-timeout 1800 -pass-header Authorization
         <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
              Require all granted
         </Directory>
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
        <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
            #Uncomment the SetHandler you want to use by default
            #SetHandler php56-fcgi-www
            #SetHandler php71-fcgi-www
        </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>

    Alias /html "/var/www/html/"
    <Directory "/var/www/html/">
        <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
            #Uncomment the SetHandler with the opposite php version
            #SetHandler php56-fcgi-www
            #SetHandler php71-fcgi-www
        </FilesMatch>
    </Directory>   

</VirtualHost>`
```

secondsite.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin Admin@secondsite.tk
    DocumentRoot /var/www/secondsite.tk/public_html
    ServerName cafegaming.tk
    ServerAlias www.secondsite.tk secondsite.tk

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.secondsite.tk [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =secondsite.tk
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

`

thirdsite.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com


    ServerAdmin admin@thirdsite.tk
    ServerName thirdsite.tk
    ServerAlias www.thirdsite.tk thirdsite.tk
    DocumentRoot /home/ogp_agent/OGP_User_Files/19/screenshots/

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.thirdsite.tk [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =thirdsite.tk
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

`

Comment: Show exactly your config file and do not obfuscate needlessly.

Comment: `apach2.conf` 
[link](https://pastebin.com/YgrJjFCz)

`000-default.conf`
[link](https://pastebin.com/cF3V5N3J)

`secondsite.tk.conf`
[link](https://pastebin.com/myuG7QSp)

`thirdsite.tk.conf`
[link](https://pastebin.com/zS88vzY6)

Comment: Provide the relevant part directly in your question, not as remote links and not as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add additional access directives to the directories that are outside of `/var/www`, because these paths are initially denied in `apache2.conf` by the following piece of code:

```bsh
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

So your virtual host configuration file should look as this:

```bsh
<VirtualHost *:80>
    #...
    DocumentRoot /home/ogp_agent/OGP_User_Files/19/screenshots/
    <Directory /home/ogp_agent/OGP_User_Files/19/screenshots/>
        # Tweak the directives according to your requirments
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
   </Directory>
    #...
</VirtualHost>
```

---

Another idea is to use the `UserDir` directive to configure *web root* directory for each user of your system. Read more:

- [Per-user web directories](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/public_html.html)
- [Apache Module mod_userdir](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_userdir.html#userdir)

---

In addition, I would do not use the `RewriteEngine` for such redirection, while there is `Redirect` directive - [review this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1031460/566421) for more information. Also probably [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1024308/566421) could be interesting for you.