# Redirect http to https

Tags: apache2

I have a small issue I cannot solve. I run Apache on Ubuntu 16.04 and after installing a Let's encrypt cert, all works except for this...

When I type mydomain.com, it goes automatically to https://mydomain.com

When I type www.mydomain.com, it goes automatically to https://mydomain.com

When I type mydomain.com, it goes automatically to https://mydomain.com

When I type http://mydomain.com, it goes automatically to https://mydomain.com

**But** when I type http://www.mydomain.com, it stays in insecure http://www.mydomain.com

Here are the conf files...

```
nuc@nuc:~$ cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

and...

```
nuc@nuc:~$ cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default-le-ssl.conf 
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated...
:-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect people after SSL is set up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031457/redirect-people-after-ssl-is-set-up)

Comment: Edwin, I will suggest you to do what @JucaPirma has suggested. For the record, in your configuration file mentioned above, you have added only one "RewriteCond" which is comparing with "=mydomain.com". You should add one more "RewriteCond" for "=www.mydomain.com" or use "RewriteCond" to match an expression.

Comment: For me it sounds as cache issue, does this happen when a new incognito window is in use?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using mod_rewrite, how about just use

```
Redirect / https://mydomain.com/
```

Answer (score 1):

**Full detailed answer on how to proceed since I had some trouble while it is very simple:**
Once you got your 3 certificates (private.key, certificate.crt, ca_bundle.crt) from Let's encrypt or https://www.sslforfree.com/ :

**1/ upload them to the remote server:**
   On the remote server that you are connected (nb: obviously you can choose another name or even location instead of 'certificates', just be consistant for after):

```
mkdir /etc/ssl/certificates
```

On your machine (assuming you unziped the 3 files in the sslforfree folder):

```
scp  ~/Downloads/sslforfree/* ubuntu@{replace with you server adress, if aws you can use the elastic IP}:/etc/ssl/certificates
```

Alternatively you can use some ftp software like filezilla or use rsync. I just think that scp myfiles ubuntu@156.185.219.228:/etc/ssl/certificates is very simple if you are using ubuntu on your own computer.

**2/ Edit the config files located at /etc/apache2/sites-available on your server**

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available && chmod 777 *
```

then use your favorite editor and you can replace in 000-default.conf :

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

with (assuming your site dns is mysite.com):

```
ServerName http.mysite.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
Redirect permanent / https://mysite.com/
```

**3/ Then edit default-ssl.conf**
(bonus: the 4th item will enable the favicon located at /var/www/html, which is obviously something you also want if you go through the hassle of getting SSL, ctrl+shirt+R to force the cache of your browser to load it later on):

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName mysite.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
AddType image/x-icon .ico
```

and enable SSL by changing the path for two first and removing the hashtag and changing the path for the third item:

```
SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certificates/certificate.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certificates/private.key

#   Server Certificate Chain:
#   Point SSLCertificateChainFile at a file containing the
#   concatenation of PEM encoded CA certificates which form the
#   certificate chain for the server certificate. Alternatively
#   the referenced file can be the same as SSLCertificateFile
#   when the CA certificates are directly appended to the server
#   certificate for convinience.
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certificates/ca_bundle.crt
```

**4/ Enable the module, default-ssl.conf and finally reload config for apache2 server:**

```
sudo a2enmod ssl &&
sudo a2ensite default-ssl.conf &&
sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

Don't forget to reset permissions to default:
    chmod 644 *

Your site is now secured through permanent redirect to https!

Comment: ok I edited, thank you ;)