# Can't access my website with domain name with DigitalOcean

Tags: apache2, dns

I'm using DigitalOcean for my hosting services and I've several domain names on the same droplets. All these domain use Let's Encrypt for SSL certificates.

---

### What's your DNS records ?

```
|--------|---------------------------|--------------------------------------------|---------------|
| Type   | Hostname                  | Value                                      | TTL (seconds) | 
|--------|---------------------------|--------------------------------------------|---------------|
| NS     | example.com               | ns1.digitalocean.com.                      | 1800          |
| NS     | example.com               | ns2.digitalocean.com.                      | 1800          |
| NS     | example.com               | ns3.digitalocean.com.                      | 1800          |
| A      | example.com               | 159.xx.xx.60.                              | 3600          |
| A      | www.example.com           | 159.xx.xx.60.                              | 3600          |
| MX     | example.com               | mailstore1.secureserver.net.               | 14400         |
| MX     | example.com               | smtp.secureserver.net.                     | 14400         |
| CNAME  | 12501762.example.com      | sendgrid.net.                              | 43200         |
| CNAME  | url9338.example.com       | sendgrid.net.                              | 43200         |
| CNAME  | s2._domainkey.example.com | s2.domainkey.u12501762.wl015.sendgrid.net. | 43200         |
| CNAME  | s1._domainkey.example.com | s1.domainkey.u12501762.wl015.sendgrid.net. | 43200         |
| CNAME  | em8980.example.com        | u12501762.wl013.sendgrid.net.              | 43200         |
|--------|---------------------------|--------------------------------------------|---------------|
```

- MX = allow the use of the GoDaddy mailbox (email like abc@example.com).
- CNAME = allow the use of SendGrid.

---

### So what's my problem?


If I type in the browser:

- example.com, I have a 404 error saying Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at example.com Port 80.
- www.example.com, all is working and it redirects to the HTTPS version.
- http://example.com, all is working and it redirects to the HTTPS version.
- https://example.com, all is working.

So the problem is only with example.com.

---

### Did you try ping function?

Yes. I ping with www.example.com and example.com and the both gave me the same IP address (my IP address).

---

### What about traceroute ?

Again, it gave me the same for both www.example.com and example.com. It pointed to my server.

---

### What about my .conf files?

Here the example.com.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Here the example.com-le-ssl.conf file:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

---

Can anyone help me with this ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried putting in a redirect at your domain registrar?

Comment: @OrganicMarble, if I make this it will not remove the DNS entry? My domain registrar is GoDaddy.

Comment: When I added Let's Encrypt, I had to go to my registrar (namecheap) and add a redirect for www.[mywebsite].com -> https://[mywebsite].com  This just reminded me of that problem. I am no expert which is why I posted a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Try to follow the advice given within the Apache's documentation and use `Redirect` directive instead of `Rewrite` rules for the redirection, as it is shown here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1031460/566421 Then flush your browser's cache ot use a new incognito window to do the test.