# apache2 ubuntu default page not redirecting to https

Tags: networking, server, apache2

Apache2 is not redirecting by default http to https on one of the rules when domain starts with `http://www`. My domain using certbot.

`000-default.conf` - disabled

`https://domain.com/`- loading correctly

`https://www.domain.com/` - loading correctly

`http://domain.com` - redirect correctly

`http://www.domain.com` - loads Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page

I tried many combinations, please see my current vhost files setup.

My `/var/www/html/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

My `/etc/apache2/sites-available/my_project.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName domain.com
        ServerAlias www.domain.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.domain.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

My `/etc/apache2/sites-available/my_project-le-ssl.conf`

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerName domain.com
        ServerAlias www.domain.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        #django app directory setup

        #django app WSGI setup

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.domain.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.domain.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

Maybe I am missing something, could you point me in right direction?

Comment: It is better to use Redirect directive for this task:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1031460/566421

Comment: @pa4080 thanks for advice but looks like it doesn't resolve issue, I changed to `Redirect` directive in both ways (with commas and without it in hostnames), set global `ServerName` variable outside `VirtualHost` also followed Apache documentation and tried few options, SO frustrating! :(

Comment: @pa4080 looks like there was some port conflict in my_project-le-ssl.conf file, two vhosts each with different port which made server to incorrect redirect