# Invalid redirect not defined on Apache2 vhost

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

Say I have the following Vhost definition in Apache2

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName dummy.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dummy
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    ServerAlias www.dummy.com
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dummy.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dummy.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dummy.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dummy
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    RewriteEngine on
    Redirect permanent / https://www.dummy.com
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

If I type

> http://dummy.com

it redirects to

> https://www.dummy.com

But if I type

> http://www.dummy.com or just www.dummy.com

It redirects to

> https://www.dummy.comindex.php/

that is not a valid url.

*what in the vhost configuration is causing this?* I cannot see where I should look for to debug and solve the issue since the vhost doesn't contains this rewrite rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Redirect` directive must be:

```
Redirect permanent / https://www.dummy.com/
```

- Note the final slash `/`.

Modify the configuration file then restart Apache2 or just reload its configuration. And then flush your browser's cache or use new incognito window to do the test.

In addition you do not need `RewriteEngine on` in order to use the `Redirect` directive (it is not rewrite rule).

Here is a similar Q&A: [Redirect people after SSL is set up](https://askubuntu.com/q/1031457/566421)

Comment: It works fine. Thanks! On the RewriteEngine on consider it a typo. Certbot was trying to setup the redirect using a rewrite rule authomatically and the rule remained there. Thanks again!