# Weird phpmyadmin url

Tags: apache2, lamp, phpmyadmin

I have question regarding phpmyadmin. Just installing Ubuntu 20.04 then setup LAMP stack. When i click Phpmyadmin icon from Activities it open in the browser using "localhostphpmyadmin" instead "localhost/phpmyadmin" as you can see in screenshot.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbjSo.png)

How can i change this?

Note: Phpmyadmin is working fine if i accessing it via localhost/phpmyadmin. The only problem when i launch it from Activities shortcut.

Edit: result of phpmyadmin.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=phpMyAdmin
Comment=MySQL management over web
Exec=sensible-browser http://localhost/phpmyadmin/
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=phpmyadmin
Categories=Development;Database;
```

apache 000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    DocumentRoot /mnt/Development

    redirect permanent  "/" "https://localhost/"

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

default-ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin admin@localhost
        ServerName localhost

        DocumentRoot /mnt/Development

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Hello, please [edit] the question and add the output of the command:                                `cat /etc/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin.desktop`.

Comment: First off find your phpmyadmin .desktop file either in /usr/share/applications/ or in ~/.local/share/applications and see what's in front of the " Exec= " parameter . It might be a typo.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi phpmyadmin .desktop result add.

Comment: Does there any additional custom Apache's configuration?

Comment: @pa4080 Openssl? if that count?

Comment: Yes, probably there is some rewrite rule or redirection directive where the end slash is missing. I mean something like this case: https://askubuntu.com/q/1207983/566421

Comment: I think it might be a different .desktop file that is being executed . When I run the command of your "Exec " parameter in my system , it opens the URI as expected .

Comment: @ParsaMousavi, by default `/usr/share/applications/phpmyadmin.desktop` is symbolic link to `/etc/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin.desktop`.

Comment: @pa4080 I add apache config in post

Comment: @ParsaMousavi i only have phpmyadmin.desktop in `/etc/phpmyadmin`

Comment: Huh, you can't use SSL/HTTPS on localhost, because the certificates are issued for a domain name (FQDN). Even for test purposes you must buy some domain name when you want to use SSL.

Comment: I would try to remove `redirect permanent  "/" "https://localhost/"` for a while, restart Apache and flush the browser's cache in order to investigate the reason of this wrong redirection.

Comment: @pa4080 i know, but if it not allowed should be an error appear? everything is fine actually, only url problem from desktop shortcut.

Comment: @pa4080 let me try

Comment: You can read also `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

Comment: Well let me do fresh install again.